# Chart.js draw y-axis only up to point

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm wondering how to draw the y-axis only up to the point of one dataset. Like in this example:

[image]

So far I've tried a hacky version by adding an inversed white background on the dataset, but because I have some offset on the x-axis the white background cuts suddently, and the Y-axis lines becomes hidden.

Does anyone know how to loop through each grid line and give it the correct length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw you own lines directly on to the `canvas` using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to draw dashed lines for individual points from the dataset.

```js
const data = [1, 3, 2];
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "line",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {
         var x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index);         
         var yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(data[index]);                  
         ctx.save();
         ctx.setLineDash([10, 5]);
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#888888';
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, yAxis.bottom);             
         ctx.lineTo(x, yTop);
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First Dataset",
      data: [1, 3, 2],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
      lineTension: 0.3
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true,
        gridLines: {
          color: 'white'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 4,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }]
    }
  }  
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="10"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a filling answer! I solved it another way for my use (by decreasing the opacity so you don't notice the lines overlapping) but I'm accepting the answer as it's a better solution for anyone else with similar problems! :)